# Utility class for robust EBO

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

In modern C++, many classes accept a [*policy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) type as a `template` parameter. The author of the class does not know in advance what kind of policy its class will be instantiated with. If the policy class is empty, it would be desirable to inherit from it so to leverage the [*empty base optimization* (EBO)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization). On the other hand, not every type can be inherited from. Counter-examples include `union`s, `class`es declared as `final` or non-`class` types like `int`.

I wrote the following utility `policy_base_t<T>` that allows library authors to make use of EBO when it is possible to inherit from `T` and fall back to delegation otherwise. It will always be possible to inherit from `policy_base_t<T>` itself. A reference to the policy object may be obtained via the (`protected`) `policy` member function.

```
#ifndef META_HXX
#define META_HXX

#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>


namespace meta
{

  namespace detail
  {

    template <typename PolicyT>
    class deriving_policy : private PolicyT
    {

    protected:

      template <typename... ArgTs>
      deriving_policy(ArgTs&&... args)
        noexcept(noexcept(PolicyT (std::declval<ArgTs>()...))) :
        PolicyT (std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...)
      {
      }

      PolicyT&
      policy() noexcept
      {
        return *this;
      }

      const PolicyT&
      policy() const noexcept
      {
        return *this;
      }

    };


    template <typename PolicyT>
    class delegating_policy
    {

    private:

      PolicyT policy_;  // not initialized

    protected:

      template <typename... ArgTs>
      delegating_policy(ArgTs&&... args)
        noexcept(noexcept(PolicyT (std::declval<ArgTs>()...))) :
        policy_ (std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...)
      {
      }

      PolicyT&
      policy() noexcept
      {
        return this->policy_;
      }

      const PolicyT&
      policy() const noexcept
      {
        return this->policy_;
      }

    };

  }  // namespace detail

  template <typename T>
  using policy_base_t = typename std::conditional
  <
    (std::is_class<T>::value && !std::is_final<T>::value),
    detail::deriving_policy<T>,
    detail::delegating_policy<T>
  >::type;

}  // namespace meta


#endif  // #ifndef META_HXX
```

I wrote the following tests. (I'm not asking for a code review of the tests; just showing them so you can see the intended usage. I'm aware that the `static_assert`ions are not mandated by the standard to pass and thus non-portable but they do pass on current GCC and Clang.)

```
#include "meta.hxx"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


namespace /* anonymous */
{

  struct empty
  {
  };

  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const empty&)
  {
    return os << "empty";
  }

  struct empty_final final
  {
  };

  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const empty_final&)
  {
    return os << "empty & final";
  }

  struct non_empty
  {
    int a;
  };

  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const non_empty& o)
  {
    return os << "non-empty [a = " << o.a << "]";
  }

  struct non_empty_final final
  {
    int a;
  };

  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const non_empty_final& o)
  {
    return os << "non-empty & final [a = " << o.a << "]";
  }

  union integer
  {
    signed int s;
    unsigned int u;
  };

  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const integer& o)
  {
    return os << "a union [signed = " << o.s << ", unsigned = " << o.u << "]";
  }

  union nothing
  {
  };

  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const nothing&)
  {
    return os << "an empty union";
  }

  template <typename PolicyT>
  class test : private meta::policy_base_t<PolicyT>
  {

    int dummy;

  public:

    template <typename... ArgTs>
    test(ArgTs&&... args) : meta::policy_base_t<PolicyT> {std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...}
    {
    }

    void
    show_policy()
    {
      std::cout << "my policy is: " << this->policy() << '\n';
    }

  };

  struct float_and_int
  {
    float f;
    int i;
  };

  struct string_and_int
  {
    std::string s;
    int i;
  };

}  // namespace /* anonymous */


int
main()
{
  test<empty> t1 {};
  t1.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t1) == sizeof(int), "expected EBO");

  test<empty_final> t2 {};
  t2.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t2) == 2 * sizeof(int), "unexpected EBO");

  test<non_empty> t3 {non_empty {42}};
  t3.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t3) == 2 * sizeof(int), "weired");

  test<non_empty_final> t4 {non_empty_final {42}};
  t4.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t4) == 2 * sizeof(int), "weired");

  test<integer> t5 {integer {-42}};
  t5.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t5) == 2 * sizeof(int), "how come?");

  test<nothing> t6 {};
  t6.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t6) == 2 * sizeof(int), "unexpected EBO");

  test<float> t7 {0.5f};
  t7.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t7) == sizeof(float_and_int), "strange");

  test<std::string> t8 {"be nice"};
  t8.show_policy();
  static_assert(sizeof(t8) == sizeof(string_and_int), "strange");

  test<std::string> t9 {};
  t9.show_policy();
}
```

I am looking for code reviews that address the following questions.

- Is the approach general and safe? (Are there `T`s for which it breaks?)
- Does it cause any overhead that could be avoided?
- Am I using `noexcept` correctly?
- Should I use uniform initialization syntax instead? (I've chosen not to because that's what the constructors of the standard library's smart pointers do as well.)

I believe that such utility could be of general use and – depending on the kind of feedback I'll get from this thread – am thinking about proposing it as an addition to the standard library.

Comment: May be the [CRTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) is a better pattern to go for implementing policies and mixin interfaces. Though that's too narrow for an answer here, thus I'm giving that hint as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code looks fine, I have one important issue and some minor comments:

**Typedefs**

One of the common uses of policy classes are their typedefs (cf. `std::iterator<>`). Using `policy_base_t<P>` hides all of those, since in the delegating case, you hid `P`, and in the deriving case, you inherited privately. So I would suggest at the very least deriving `public`ally from `PolicyT` and exposing it as a typedef in both cases:

```
using Policy = PolicyT;
```

That at least would handle most of the cases. Presumably nobody is adding typedefs to their `final` policy right?

**Inherit constructors too**

Rather than explicitly forwarding args to the constructor in `deriving_policy`, you could just `using PolicyT::PolicyT;` Does the same thing and saves a bunch of typing.

**Unecessary `this->`**

In `delegating_policy`, you don't need `this->` where you use it, you can just write `policy_`. It's a member, so it's not dependent.

**Excessive vertical spacing**

You don't need to double space around accessor labels or namespaces. It just makes it harder to fit everything on one window.

**Use the aliases**

Prefer the C++14 `std::conditional_t` to `typename std::conditional<blah, blah, blah>::type`. If you don't have a C++14 compiler, write the alias somewhere and still use it.

Comment: I like the suggested `typedef`. While the user of the policy always knows its type (the `T` used to instantiate `policy_base_t`), it's easy to do and might be useful. I went for `private` inheritance to give either wrapper type the same interface, preventing people to rely on something that is only available if `T` is not `final`. There is no way to make the `typedef`s available in the `delegating_policy` or am I missing something?

Comment: @5gon12eder Nope, definitely no way. Unless you know exactly what they are up front and just manually write them.